# How to implement redo of draw interaction in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers

In the case of undo, this is implemented using drawInteraction.removeLastPoint().

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-features.html

But I don't know how to implement redo.

The redo function should be available when drawing interaction is active.

Should I use "setGeometry"?

Answer (score 1):

I found append Coordinates in openlayers api.

drawinteraction.appendCoordinates([coordinate]);

Comment: How do you get the currently being edited coordinate?

Comment: Interaction.sketchCoords_
I used this.

Comment: Interesting. On which event are you calling it?

Comment: I use this when the user clicks the redo button.